# How to access form data sent using add.js in Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I am sending properties[price] to the cart using add.js in Shopify and I a would like to know how to display it on the cart. The tests that I have run should show £110.79 but instead show £1.11 and I have no idea why. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
    function modifyCartBtn(price) {
    document.getElementById('AddToCart-product-template').addEventListener('click', function() {
      var modifiedPrice = Number(price);
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('id', {{ product.variants.first.id }});
      formData.append('quantity', 1);
      formData.append('properties[price]', price.toString());
  
      fetch('/cart/add.js', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: new URLSearchParams(formData),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      // Handle the response if needed
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
  });
}

{% for item in cart.items %}
        <p>Product: {{ item.product.title }}</p>
        <p>Price: {{ item.price | money }}</p>
        <p>Modified Price: {{ item.properties.price | money }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Shopify cart items we can not display the products properties without for loop. So, please you can try like below code for this ("Modified Price: {{ item.properties.price | money }}") line.

```html
{%- for property in item.properties -%}
  {%- assign property_first_char = property.first | slice: 0 -%}
  {%- if property.last != blank and property_first_char != '_' -%}
    <div class="product-option">
      <dt>{{ property.first }}:</dt>
      <dd>
        {%- if property.last contains 'price' -%}
            {{ property.last }}
        {%- else -%}
          {{ property.last }}
        {%- endif -%}
      </dd>
    </div>
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Comment: Thanks @VrMistry, I have added this in just under the Modified price line but nothing is displaying. Have I missed something?

Comment: @CorbonCoder, Can you please check by print {{ item.properties }} only.

Comment: @CorbonCoder, One more thing can you please check your cart item json you can get that price property in that JSON.

Comment: I tried:
<dd>
                {%- if property.last contains 'price' -%}
                    {{ item.properties }}
                {%- else -%}
                  {{ property.last }}
                {%- endif -%}
              </dd>

And got: 

Modified Price: £1.11

price:
110.79

Comment: Can you please check your cart items JSON by using this URL "https://[store-URL]/cart.json"

In that items JSON you can get properties they that is displayed it with above forloop code.

Comment: In the JSON I see this: "items":[{"id":40903326409,"properties":{"price":"110.79"},"quantity":1,"variant_id":40903326409,

Comment: Yes, this is correct. So above code is need worked for you.